# Handling connection loss when requesting a REST API multiple times / in a loop (client side)

Tags: node.js, rest, client-side, api-design

I'm working on a project where I'm creating a full-stack web app for processing audit's on equipments. I use a SPA framework for the frontend and an express server with Nodejs for the backend (REST API).

In the app itself I work with sessions to log the answers of a questionary with a bunch of predefined questions (history function). Here an audit can have multiple sessions. A session can have multiple answers refering to the predefined questions (same as the previous session). 
Therefore, each time the audit is opened by the user, a new session is generated in which all answers from the previous session are copied. When the session is created, many small requests are sent to the server on the client in a loop (Has to be atomic).

My question is, what is a good practice to **handle connection loss while sending many small requests to the API** in a loop (client side)? Because if the connection from the client to the server is aborted during session creation, inconsistent data will be generated. How do I deal with this problem to avoid inconsistencies?

One idea was, to apply business logic to the relevant request (session endpoint), where I create the session with the items internally on the server. But it is known that implementing business logic in a rest api is not good practice.

*Analogous to this fact, you can take as an example order items and an order*

Can someone help me with this problem or has any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are trying to use sessions as part of your [REST API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) and that's against RESTfulness (server functions should be stateless). You can use a [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) and make the client responsible for providing the data associated with its session (if data is small enough).

Comment: Sorry, apparently I could not express myself clearly. Server functions are still stateless. The sessions refer to the data in the database not to server functions. Analogous to this fact, you can take as an example order items and an order

Comment: @erdi8: If you edit the question and elaborate second paragraph: What states are used for, what is at client side and what at server side (sessions for example) and why such a session is needed in first place. I will delete this answer and write one for the updated question.

Comment: I hope it is clearer now, if not, please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @erdi8: Worrying about connection loss in a loop sounds to me a statefull server or you are worrying about underlying protocol (TCP) which is statefull itself and handles errors otherwise client can resume from where it was aborted if there is no state involved. If data if already transferred to server I don't understand why you need multiple requests to server and need them to be as part of a transaction (server state). You can unify those small requests and send them as a single API call or if it is a multipart operation at server side, unify them at server side over a single API endpoint.

Comment: @Xarqon: Unifying it over a single/seperated endpoint was my first thought. But I did not know if this was a valid solution according to a restful service, because it would contain a little business logic.

Comment: @erdi8: That's a valid solution. Consider transferring X$ from A to B while there are just `deposit` and `withdraw` endpoints while the client is mobile and can gather required data at two pages (sender, receiver of money). Then a unification is needed at client side (from whom, to whom, what amount) and a single API endpoint to do the transfer. This approach still requires state and transaction at server/database side while from client point of view is stateless.